# Navigation has failed: takes to the assembly browser

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I've been working on a mobile app using Xamarin.Forms in Visual Studio for Mac. I ran into a glitch that I have never encountered before. When I click on a button, which generates an event and supposedly should be navigating to the screen that I'm assigning, but it's not happening. Instead the screen on the emulator glitches and an assembly browser is opened(see the photo attached 1.0).Furthermore, when I choose another screen to be navigated to:I click the same button and everything works just fine. The page has been declared in AppShell and there is literally nothing else that can be done. The peculiar thing is, that the emulator does not display an error.
Is there a solution to fixing this glitch?

[the screenshot of the glitch 1.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TvJJ.jpg)
[Screenshot of the Xaml file of the screen that causes the glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbBQM.png)

[Screenshot of the Xaml.cs file of the screen that causes the glitch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FITYg.png)

The code of the Xaml file that causes the glitch:

{

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <<ContentPage
        xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        x:Class="Rollthedice3._0.Views.FirstPlayer"
        Title="First Player">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
    
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
               
    
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    
    
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Accent}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
               
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>
             
    
            
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>

}
The code of the Xaml.cs file that causes the glitch:
{

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using Rollthedice3._0.ViewModels;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using System.IO;
    
    
    namespace Rollthedice3._0.Views
    {
        public partial class FirstPlayer : ContentPage
        {
            public FirstPlayer()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
    
                
            }
        }
    }
```

}

[The glitch on an ios simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKRYg.png)

Comment: Please post the relevant code.  Do you have any exception handling setup?  Have you tried with a different emulator image or physical device?

Comment: I've added the screenshots of the code and yes I tried with different emulators. The same glitch occurs.

Comment: do NOT post code as screenshots.  Take the time to paste the code and properly format it

Comment: I think there is sth wrong with the code in the xaml file, because I've just copied the code from that file and pasted it into the other content page(the page was opening with its previous code when button was clicked), as soon as I pasted the code from the glitching file,I got the same error.

Comment: comment out the XAML and re-add it line by line until you find the offender

Comment: `<<ContentPage`: does the xaml really start with two `<`s?

Comment: Correcting the ContentPage did not help, the program still terminates imperceptibly. I tried running this program on ios simulator, it states that the exception has been thrown(I added the screenshot of the message). How could I fix the glitch?

Comment: Could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via Github repo?